# mybatis where condition with string parameter is not working

Tags: sql-update, mybatis

my (mybatis 3.2.8) update query is not working when i pass string parameter in where condition. It works if i hard code and set STTS='**COMPLETE**'. I tried logging the SQL query its showing the parameter correctly.

```
UPDATE CUST SET LAST_UPDT_DT=#{lastUpdtd,javaType=Date,jdbcType=DATE}
WHERE CUST_NUM=#{custNum,javaType=int,jdbcType=INTEGER} 
AND STATUS=#{status,javaType=String,jdbcType=VARCHAR2}
```

There are no errors, it runs the update query and commits as normal but it doesn't really update the table. Please let me know if there is any issue with string arguments in mybatis.

Comment: post your log, maybe that will help others to help you.

Comment: No errors in the logs everything goes well....    here is update log      ==> Preparing: UPDATE CUST LAST_UPDT_DT=?WHERE CUST_NUM=? AND STATUS=? 
==> Parameters: 2016-02-11(Date), 127(Integer), 'COMPLETE'(String)
input count: 1, update counts: 1

Comment: Sorry, but that doesn't look like a code problem. The update seems to work. Are you sure, that your expectations are correct?

Answer (score 1):

No VARCHAR2 in the jdbcType enum, you can check the jdbcType here:
[JdbcType](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/apidocs/reference/org/apache/ibatis/type/JdbcType.html)

You can change the last line from:

```
AND STATUS=#{status,javaType=String,jdbcType=VARCHAR2}
```

To (or to the right jdbc type that fits your dataType):

```
AND STATUS=#{status,javaType=String,jdbcType=VARCHAR}
```